# Polygon Top addresses Polygon chain vs Ethereum chain

Tags: etherscan, ethereum-wallet-dapp, addresses, polygon, polygon-bridge

If I check Polygon top addresses on Polygon chain, I see the following list on https://polygonscan.com/accounts. With top1 address  [0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010](https://polygonscan.com/address/0x0000000000000000000000000000000000001010) containing 9,070,304,832.222338543972671195 MATIC. While on Ethereum chain we have different [top account balances](https://etherscan.io/token/tokenholderchart/0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0?range=500). With top1 [0x5e3Ef299fDDf15eAa0432E6e66473ace8c13D908](https://etherscan.io/token/0x7d1afa7b718fb893db30a3abc0cfc608aacfebb0?a=0x5e3ef299fddf15eaa0432e6e66473ace8c13d908) equal 3,824,840,428 MATIC. Why there is such difference between polygon and ethereum chain top accounts? And is there any connection between those two MATIC chains?